# My ifconfig: command not found for some reason

Tags: terminal, mac, bash

I'm using Mac Sierra version 10.13.6 and when I try using ifconfig it just outputs

```
-bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

And, when I run $PATH, I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/********/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/**********/google-cloud-sdk:/usr/bin:/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: To see the value of `$PATH` (or any other variable), use `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

The `ifconfig` binary is located in `/sbin/` which doesn't seem to be in your $PATH.

You can add it by appending the line `/sbin` to `/etc/paths`.

Comment: It should already be there. My guess is that /sbin (and /usr/sbin) are being removed by something in a shell init file (~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, or something like that).